# tikzpicture blank in preview

Tags: tikz-pgf, preview

Using preview-latex to preview the tikzpicture environment shows either a blank rectangle in pdf mode or simply produces no preview file in ps mode.

I am using aquamacs 23.3a, using auctex and gs 9.04.

I tested multiple file format outputs and preview options.  I don't see any errors or warning pop up either, so I can't tell for sure if the error lies with ghostscript, auctex or preview.

The following previews a blank for the entire tikzpicture environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[draw] {tikz rectangle};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to see what exactly goes wrong where?

Comment: Have you tried to create a preview by hand, i.e. using the preview-package in your LaTeX document and \begin{preview} ... \end{preview} ?

Comment: It is creating a preview, adding a preview environment around it manually gives the same effect: blank preview.

Comment: Does this only happen with a picture, or also with just a text document? Have you tried viewing the PDF in Adobe Acrobat?

Comment: I'm talking about the preview images generated, the complete pdf generates just fine with text and all.  It's just the preview images generated by preview/gs that are empty.

Comment: You could try adding `\usepackage[active,float]{preview}\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}` as the last package. If that is not enough, try wrapping `tikzpicture` within a \begin{figure}...\end{figure}` as `preview-latex` might be looking for a float.

Comment: @PeterGrill Would you turn your comment into an answer?

Comment: @egreg: Done...

Answer (score 5):

You should add

```
\usepackage[active,float]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
```

as the last package.

If that is not enough, try wrapping the `tikzpicture` within a `\begin{figure}...\end{figure}` as `preview-latex` might be looking for a float.